# Can composite decking be installed on plastic bases?

Tags: deck, composite

I live in UK and I'm planning to install some composite decking in my garden. I see there are two options for me here:

1. [Click deck tiles](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Eva-Tech-Composite-Grey-Grooved-Deck-Tile-300-x-300mm-Pk-4/p/223562)
2. [Composite deck boards](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Eva-Tech-Xavia-Composite-Deckboard-I-Series-23mm-x-137mm-x-2-2m-Pk-5/p/210369)

Can either of these be installed on a [plastic base](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Ecobase-Fastfit-System-Shed-Base-for-8-ft-x-6-ft-Sheds/p/150219) that is filled with gravel?

I'm not sure how I can fix the composite deck boards to stay in place. Has anyone tried this and had success?

Comment: You'll have to be careful with this because it could violate local building codes and could be a tripping, falling hazard.

Comment: Would try the place they all are coming from.  They should know best and probably will have the right fasteners to do it.  Only time have seen those plastic bases were advertised to stabilized muddy pastures/walks on farms.